# Python Jupyter notebook SHAP force_plot, how to change the background color or text color in the dark theme?

Tags: python, html, node.js, jupyter-notebook, shap

[image]

Is there any way that I can change the shap plot background color or text color in the dark theme?
I need either the white background or white text.

The plot is an object of IPython.core.display.HTML.

It is generated by

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1][0,:], X_test.iloc[0,:],link="logit")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding the argument of `matplotlib=True`, the problem is solved.

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1][0,:], X_test.iloc[0,:],link="logit", matplotlib=True)
```

It seems the plot is created with matplotlib on a html file.

To plot properly, firstly I used 
`style.use('seaborn-dark')`
in the dark model of Jupyter notebook.

Comment: This works (thanks for the style tip!), however: you'll lose plot interactivity, won't you? Furthermore: `"matplotlib = True is not yet supported for force plots with multiple samples!"` - which means you can't use it when inspecting several predictions at once...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to export the figure as an html file, and open that in the browser:

```py
p = shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1][0,:], X_test.iloc[0,:],link="logit")
shap.save_html('my_force_plot.html', p)
```

But I guess a light color scheme might also circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution on Shap's Github (Dark mode problem). Try little "HTML correction" from Ipython.display. I've added 2 lines to your code:

```
force_plot = shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1][0,:], X_test.iloc[0,:],link="logit")

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(f"<div style='background-color:Lavender;'>{shap.getjs() + force_plot.html()}</div>")
```

Comment: Could you provide some context with this answer? As it is currently written, it may be difficult for people to understand how this answers the question.